# Particle moving almost at the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, mass-energy, higgs

I have been wondering for a while. Is it possible that when a body or a particle moves close to the speed of light, it interacts more with the Higgs boson? If so does that explain why moving at the speed of light increases relativistic mass?

Comment: Moving close to the speed of mass does NOT increase the REST mass! Your confusion might come from the concept of relativistic mass, which is not really used by physicists since it is confusing and not helpful.

Comment: Well thanks, but for what I know, mass increases when we go close to the speed of light right?

Comment: No it does not. Look for example at https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23991/

Comment: I understand now

Answer (score 1):

The Higgs field couples to all particles with mass due to processes explained in the framework of quantum field theory. It has nothing to do with the fact that an object is moving - relativistic mass (which itself is no longer considered a useful concept) and the Higgs mechanism are not related this way ie., a particle does not couple to the Higgs field more strongly due only to the fact that it’s velocity is increasing.