# How far could the LHC "fire" a proton into space if we (outside LHC) ignore all interactions but gravity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, large-hadron-collider, estimation, escape-velocity

Very simple question, and frankly quite a silly one, but I'm currently writing a lecture for secondary school kids and I'd love to tell them how far the Large Hadron Collider could fire a proton.

The talk is actually about space, so what I'd really like to know is how would the velocity of the proton would compare to, for example, the necessary escape velocity for the proton to escape the Milky Way?

As the talk is mostly about energetics and kinematics I'd be keen to ignore the effect of the protons charge and just look at the kinetic energy being converted to gravitational potential.

Comment: "how would the escape velocity of the proton compare to, for example, the escape velocity from the Milky Way?" --- this doesn't make sense to me. What do you mean by this? In particular, what do you mean by the escape velocity of a proton.

Comment: Edited the question to helpfully be a bit clearer. Could also be phrased in terms of energy, what's the largest scale object the proton would have sufficient energy to escape from?

Comment: LHC protons are ultrarelativistic and should basically be able to escape anything that's not a black hole; as to the escape velocity of the Milky Way, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity#List_of_escape_velocities) it's less than that of the sun and thus well below the speed of light (though I cannot confirm right now as it's nightime where I'm sitting ;)).

Comment: That value is from the galactic radius, although it's true it has a few orders of magnitude to spare on ultra-relativistic speeds. It doesn't tell you however, the speed a body would need to be moving, starting at earth, to escape the milky way

Comment: @Zephyr: the value I was getting at was at *solar system* galactic radius; you're right that the relevant quantity is actually the root of the sum of the appropriate escape velocities (earth from surface, sun from earth orbit, milky way from solar system) squared, but the first two are negligible

Comment: Oops, very true, but that's still quite a low lower bound on how far this proton i going. Surely there must be some scale of cosmic object on which it will be bound?

Comment: If gravitational interactions in multiple star systems can fling a _star_ clear out of the galaxy, into deep space, I don't see why a proton moving at .999999c or so would have any trouble escaping the galaxy. This is of course ignoring any drag due to collisions with other stuff, or attraction/repulsion due to electrical charge, or bending of the trajectory due to magnetic fields. Ignoring all that stuff, an accelerated proton should easily escape the galaxy, and probably even a Supergroup's gravity.

Answer (score 3):

I think I get what you're after. You're looking for a qualitative handle on just how fast those protons are slinging it...

You might try considering the speed *differential* between an LHC proton and a photon that is launched at the same time. As others have noted the proton is ultra-relativistic (its kinetic energy is *waaay* greater than its rest-mass), so working out an actual speed is a bit tricky. Luckily, someone [already did it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716/relativistic-speed-energy-relation-is-this-correct).

Using this value, the proton is moving at a speed of $(1 - 9\times10^{-9})c$ and the photon is moving at $c$. So the proton is 2.7 $ms^{-1}$ slower than the photon. The photon is getting away from the the proton at about the speed of a brisk walk.