# How to compute the speed of a cosmic ray from its energy?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, velocity, cosmic-rays

How can you compute the speed of a cosmic ray from its type and measured energy?

For example, if a cosmic ray were said to be a proton of 10 GeV, how would you compute the velocity of that cosmic ray?

Comment: Since the rest mass of a proton is slightly under 1 GeV, so this is clearly a relativistic calculation. A previous question (going quite a ways back) has the right answer: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716/relativistic-speed-energy-relation-is-this-correct